# How to submit the form one time after multiple success response Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, jquery-events

In my project I'm uploading multiple images to a product and I append the `uuid`'s of the images from the response in hidden fields within my form.

I need to submit the form only one time when I get all the `uuid`'s in the response appends the form.

In my case the form submits multiple times, suppose if I uploads 3 images the form submits 3 times.

Please suggest me a way that I could submit the form only one time after all the images upload?

Here's the script:

```
<script>
$('#submit_form').on('click', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    uploadPhotos(function() {});

});


function uploadPhotos(callback) {
// upload files
var $photos = $('#frmAddNewProduct input[type="file"]');

$photos.each(function(fi, el) {
    var files = el.files;
    if (files.length != 0 ) {
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var data = new FormData();
            data.append('_token', '{{ csrf_token() }}');
            data.append('upload_dir', 'products/images');
            data.append('category', 'product');
            data.append('file', files[i]);
            $.ajax({

            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            url: '{{ url("pharmacy/files")}}',
            success: function (res) {

                if (res.payload && res.payload.uuid) {
                    var $input = $('<input type="hidden" name="images[]">').val(res.payload.uuid);
                    var $message = res.payload.message;
                    $('#frmAddNewProduct').append($input);


                    // TODO : Form submits multiple times here should fix

                        // Submit form after appending the input
                        $('#frmAddNewProduct').submit();

                }

            },

        });


    }
}
});

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move the for-loop inside for appending your image only

```
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    data.append(i, files[i]);
}
```

But you need to handle the multiple files on the server-side.

Full:

```
function uploadPhotos(callback) {
    // upload files
    var $photos = $('#frmAddNewProduct input[type="file"]');

    $photos.each(function(fi, el) {
        var files = el.files;
        if (files.length != 0) {

            var data = new FormData();
            data.append('_token', '{{ csrf_token() }}');
            data.append('upload_dir', 'products/images');
            data.append('category', 'product');
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                data.append(i, files[i]);
            }

            $.ajax({

                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                type: 'POST',
                data: data,
                url: '{{ url("pharmacy/files")}}',
                success: function(res) {

                    if (res.payload && res.payload.uuid) {
                        var $input = $('<input type="hidden" name="images[]">').val(res.payload.uuid);
                        var $message = res.payload.message;
                        $('#frmAddNewProduct').append($input);


                        // TODO : Form submits multiple times here should fix

                        // Submit form after appending the input
                        $('#frmAddNewProduct').submit();

                    }

                },

            });



        }
    });

}
```